# SSL certificate handshake exception aborts DownloadManager image download from CloudFront

Tags: android, amazon-cloudfront

In my Android app I am trying to download media files(image, video) from Amazon service CloudFront.

Sample link: https://testcdn.grouvi.org/uploads/94498583-94c4-44b8-911e-2e0c6bcc4b27/86e55069-2627-4c96-9cbe-98fc87f2eb1b.jpg

I use this code.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUrl);
String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(messageComponent.getMediaUrl());
final String fname = "newfilename" + "." + mimeType;
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(context.getResources().getString(R.string.tmp_dir_path), fname);
                    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
long downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

On `Nexus 5(Lolipop), Samsung S5(Kitkat)` image is downloading. But on `Xaiomi(Kitkat), LG L Fino(Kitkat)` image is not downloading. And `DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES` gives negative -1 value

But when I use direct Amazon link
https://s3.amazonaws.com/grouvi_s/uploads/1c8f59f6-d1a9-430f-ab5c-2a89bcfbe14b/47e461a3-efa9-421a-8bc9-9b18053cbbbc.jpg

All phones can download media files.

**Edit 1**

I just found in logs the probable cause of the problem:

```
W/DownloadManager﹕ Aborting request for download 840: while trying to execute request: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x752a9a60: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x7362ad74:0x00000000)
```

As I understand its some kind of certificate problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this CVE, I think it deals with your issue: http://aws.amazon.com/security/security-bulletins/CVE-2014-3566-advisory/

It means that by default SSLv3 is disabled because it is not considered secure

Comment: Is there any fix for that? Just landed on this page searching for the same issue.
In my case the server not allowing downloads (via the `DownloadManager`) in API below 21 is github.com

Comment: Since my original response, SSLv3 didn't become more secure or accepted, so good path forward is to upgrade client so it could use supported protocol and cypher suite.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm going to drop the system Downloadmanager for that task.